# Change the width of standard subscribe button to something lesser than 225

Tags: facebook, button, width, subscribe

Is there a way to change the width of Facebook's "standard layout, with facepile" [Subscribe Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) to something lesser than FB-prescribed minimal width of 225 pixels? (So that to fit into an existing site's design.) FB documentation on the above referenced page says,

> **layout** - there are three options. 
>   **standard** - displays social text to the right of the button and friends' profile photos below. **Minimum width: 225 pixels**, *etc*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You can do this by modifying the iframe CSS

```
.fb-subscribe.fb_iframe_widget {
max-width: 150px !important;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

However, the method will mean the standard text could be obscured. You could [consult this article](http://www.labnol.org/internet/facebook-like-css/20755/) to see if it's possible to further hack the css